# Is there an env var that lets a program know if the user running it has the GUI on the screen in Windows?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, environment-variables

In Windows a user state can be:

- Logged on
- Logged off
- Switched off

  - Let me clarify, this state is the state where the user is still logged in, but another user came and switched to another account; the original users programs and windows are still there and and running, but from the monitor only the Windows from the account that was switched to account appear.

So, is there an Environment Variable in Widnows, that one can check to see if the account running the program is or is not in the "switched off" state?

Comment: The switched-off state can occur while a program is running. Environment variables are snapshotted at process creation. You can ask WTSQuerySessionInformation for the WTSConnectState.

Comment: @RaymondChen I didn’t know that ENV Vars are snapshotted thanks!

Comment: You probably knew it (and even took advantage of it) but never realized it. If environment variables were shared, then it wouldn't be possible to run two batch files at the same time, since each one would corrupt the other's variables. To demonstrate, open two command prompts. Set an environment variable in one command prompt. `set TEST=42`. Then try to read it in the other: `echo %TEST%`.

Comment: @RaymondChen What are `WTS*` that you mentioned above?  are they cmd arguments, PowerShell functions / cmdlets?

Comment: You can type them into a search engine to learn what they are.

Answer (score 0):

There is no environment variable you can check. Environment variables are not dynamically updated by the system.

As mentioned in the comments, a real application can call `WTSQuerySessionInformation` to get information about the session but applications should not pull to determine if the state has changed. Applications should call [`WTSRegisterSessionNotification`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wtsapi32/nf-wtsapi32-wtsregistersessionnotification) so they get the `WM_WTSSESSION_CHANGE` message sent to their window when the state changes.